# Hide action parameters with [BindNever] attribute from swagger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to hide parameters with the `BindNever` attribute in actions from SwaggerUI.
My action:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
[TryGetUserByIdValidation(GetAsUserReadDto = true, UserArgumentName = "userDto")]
public virtual ActionResult<ApiResult<User>> Get(int id,
    [BindNever] UserReadDto userDto)
{
    var res = new ApiResult<UserReadDto>()
        .WithData(userDto);

    return Ok(res);
}
```

In SwaggerUI I can pass the `[BindNever] UserReadDto userDto` as JSON in the request body, but the method is GET so I get an error in swaggerUI.
Why do I have a `BindNever` parameter in my action? I'm filling it with `TryGetUserByIdValidation` ActionFilter which is above my action. It handles all the mappings and errors. I'm preventing binding for that parameter with `BindNever` but it is not fully compatible with API so sometimes I have to use it with `FromForm` or any `From...` attribute except `FromBody`.

I have tried this `OperationFilter`.

```
public class SwaggerExcludeBindNeverFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var paramsToHide = context.MethodInfo.GetParameters()
                            .Where(para => para.CustomAttributes.Any(att => att.AttributeType == typeof(BindNeverAttribute)))
                            .ToList();

        if (paramsToHide.Any())
        {
            // What to do now?
            operation.RequestBody.Content.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

And add to swagger:

```
options.OperationFilter<SwaggerExcludeBindNeverFilter>();
```

But this code removes all `RequestBody.Content` and as I said it can be in Form or anywhere else.

- Swagger should not send or even show this.
- You can tell me which attribute should I use to prevent Binding and show it in swagger.
- I'm using Asp.Net Core 5.

Comment: So... rather than doing things right and getting `userDto` from a common place (like a service or one of the many other ways), you want to do a dozen things to "hide" that parameter? This doesn't sound too correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that I can't add a service to `HttpContext.RequestServices` after a request was made and get it in action parameter with `[FromServices]` attribute (error: this service is not registered).

So I pass the data with the `HttpContext.Items[]` dictionary.

In `TryGetUserByIdValidation` ActionFilter:

```
// pervious code
// context.ActionArguments[UserArgumentName] = user;

context.HttpContext.Items[ItemKey] = user; // < set the item
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
[TryGetUserByIdValidation(GetAsUserReadDto = true, ItemKey = "userDto")]
public virtual ActionResult<ApiResult<User>> Get(int id)
{
    UserReadDto userDto = HttpContext.Items[nameof(userDto)] as UserReadDto; // < get the item

    var res = new ApiResult<UserReadDto>()
        .WithData(userDto);

    return Ok(res);
}
```

This is just a whitewash answer, it works for me. It does not have anything to do with `Swagger` so please post an answer to hide `[BindNever]` action parameters.  To accept that.